# What is the equivalent ee.Image.not() in Rgee

Tags: r, google-earth-engine, rgee

I try to replicate this gee line

```
directions=directions.addBands(directions.select(0).not().multiply(5));
```

in rgee as

```
directions<-directions$addBands(directions$select(0)$not()$multiply(5))
```

I get the error `AttributeError: 'Image' object has no attribute 'not'`

Answer (score 1):

It's likely "Not", as that is what the python package uses, and rgee goes through the python client.

Comment: This solved the problem! Thank you